# Dialog Box not inheriting Main WIndow's metro style (Elysium SDK)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, microsoft-metro

I created a dialog box in a WPF Application that uses the Elysium SDK for metro-styling. I used the MessageBox utility class for displaying the dialog box but unlike the main window (and every other control there in) that are metro-styled by default, the dialog box came out as an ugly default windows dialog box which really looks out of place in the application. How can I get Elysium to style my dialog boxes too by default?

Answer (score 1):

The Dialog box is just a wrapper around the OS dialog windows.  If you want to control the look, then create your own window and show it modally.

If you need to get a result back from the dialog, set the dialogresult as shown here.

[getting a dialogresult from a WPF window](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2010/03/22/getting-a-dialogresult-from-a-wpf-window/)

Comment: I was hoping there'll be a way around this without going through the hassle. I guess WPF (or Elysium) is not yet as mature as I thought. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I shouldn't be too hard.  Add a new window to your project, use Elysium to style the window, then call the ShowDialog() method on your new window.